# how to install a package in running vm instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

while we have connect to compute engine and ssh to one of the engine
when we try to run below command

```
 sudo apt-get packagename 

 error: -bash: apt: command not found
```

is there any way to install in the running instance

Comment: What is the OS on the VM? What @martin-zeitler mention can be helpful but you need to provide more details

Answer (score 1):

You should have chosen an Ubuntu image, when expecting `apt-get` to function.
The command is probably `sudo dnf install` - that's depending on the image.